# Checkable ImageView

Tags: android

Does anybody know if it possible to make ImageView checkable. I try to use State-list drawable resource in my project where I define pictures for my ImageView check states, but there is no property to make ImageView checkable, only clickable.

Maybe anybody knows a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of making an ImageView checkable you can set a state list drawable as background for a checkbox which will automatically flip the images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checkable="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_default" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Yes, this is good desision, but this approach doesn't allow me to get rid of standard checkbox icon. I get checkbox icon with my icon at background.

Comment: That's ok, I found how to avoid this deffect: <android:button=@drawable/selector" Thank you so much)))

Comment: This works well except that CheckBox doesn't have an attribute "adjustViewBounds". So when I change from an ImageView to a CheckBox, my image gets distorted in size. Any ideas?

Comment: My images were getting clipped. So I made the checkBox size larger. How is your image getting distorted?

Comment: i used android:button="@null", i was getting weird overlay effect with certain fixed size checkbox when doing android:button="@drawable/selector"

Answer (score 33):

Use this custom ImageView implementation (taken from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-platform-apps/Contacts/com/android/contacts/ui/widget/CheckableImageView.java.htm)) :

```
public class CheckableImageView extends ImageView implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;

    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = { android.R.attr.state_checked };

    public CheckableImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(final int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked())
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(final boolean checked) {
        if (mChecked == checked)
            return;
        mChecked = checked;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Updated, Kotlin solution:

```
class CheckableImageView : AppCompatImageView, Checkable {
    private var mChecked = false

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {}
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {}

    override fun onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace: Int): IntArray {
        val drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1)
        if (isChecked) mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET)
        return drawableState
    }

    override fun toggle() {
        isChecked = !mChecked
    }

    override fun isChecked(): Boolean {
        return mChecked
    }

    override fun setChecked(checked: Boolean) {
        if (mChecked == checked) return
        mChecked = checked
        refreshDrawableState()
    }

    companion object {
        private val CHECKED_STATE_SET = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked)
    }
}
```

Comment: URL no longer valid :(

Comment: @kilaka i don't think it had a lot of important code. i just wanted to give credits to whoever done it. maybe this is a similar code (sorry i don't remember what it had) : https://github.com/chrisbanes/photup/blob/master/client/src/uk/co/senab/photup/views/CheckableImageView.java

Comment: The state of the CheckableImageView doesn't change upon clicking on the imageview.

Comment: yes, you need to toggle it yourself, or just add the method of clicking on it within the view. i didn't write it for clicking. i wrote it for being able to be toggled (can be done from outside, not necessarily by clicking).

Comment: I overwritten the `performClick()` method invoked toggle in it. Did the trick.

Comment: @kilaka yes, as i've written, this code wasn't intended to be a toggle button . it was intended to be exactly what a checkable imageView would be - to have checkable states and drawables.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I think you should add the performClick() part that AlikElzin-kilaka suggested. That way the ImageView will work exactly as a CheckBox

Comment: @ZShock Again, it's not intended to be a CheckBox. It's intended to be a checkable-ImageView. An ImageView that has a Checkable state. I don't force you to have a clicking behavior for it.

Answer (score 3):

I implements OnClickListener from android developer's code for direct checking.

```
public class CheckableImageView extends ImageView implements Checkable, View.OnClickListener {
    private boolean mChecked;

    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = { android.R.attr.state_checked };

    public CheckableImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(final int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked())
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(final boolean checked) {
        if (mChecked == checked)
            return;
        mChecked = checked;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      toggle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want change check state while clicking on ImageView, change "extend ImageView" to CompoundButton.

```
public class CheckableImageView extends CompoundButton {

    public CheckableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private static final int[] CheckedStateSet = {android.R.attr.state_checked};

    public void setChecked(boolean b) {
        boolean oldState = isChecked();
        super.setChecked(b);
        if (b != oldState) {
            refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CheckedStateSet);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        invalidate();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

this what i used in my app

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private boolean paused = false;  

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.imageview_pause:

                paused = !paused;

                if (paused) {

                    btn_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_key_pressed);

                }else{

                    btn_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_key);
                }

                break;
        }
}
}
```