# Toggle button using two image on different state

Tags: android, togglebutton

I need to make a toggle button using two image instead of ON/OFF state.

At off state i set a background image.But the OFF text can not removed while i use background image.

And i can not set another image on ON state by clicking the toggle button :(
I am new in android.
I hope you guys help me get out of this problem

Comment: You can check:  
1-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533038/android-specify-two-different-images-for-togglebutton-using-xml  
2- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100034/setting-image-source-for-togglebutton

Comment: Note that if you only use images to toggle, you could have something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322619/878126

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Do this:

```
<ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/check"   <!--check.xml-->
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

create check.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_image"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_image"
        android:state_checked="false"/>

 </selector>
```

Comment: Add two images(selected/unselected) in check.xml which will work as two different states of toggle button

Comment: Did you have a problem with background being stretched?

Comment: No, not at all @MikeBevz. Why are you getting image stretched?

Comment: @MikeBevz You are probably using image of wrong resolution...... try with some different resolution images!

Comment: When i set a background selector, the toggle buttons background is just transparent. Ive checked size, color etc and even applied other selectors that I know work. any ideas?

Comment: android:textOn=""
        android:textOff="" was what i was looking for

Comment: What is the reason of setting focusable and focusableInTouchMode to false?

Comment: I was using a switch with a selector and the background looked normal. When I tried this approach, it stretched the background out. Any idea why?

Comment: Since it looks like others had this problem as well, I'm adding my solution here. Add `android:background="@null"` and `android:drawableRight="@drawable/check"`. Usually I've found toggle buttons are right-justified. If you need it left-justified, use `android:drawableLeft`

Comment: Awesome man, android:textOn="" android:textOff="" is fabolous idea,Thanks

Comment: @Patrick But what if you want it center justified?... on all devices. So let's not get into margins and padding.

Answer (score 48):

AkashG's solution don't work for me. When I set up check.xml to background it's just stratched in vertical direction. To solve this problem you should set up check.xml to "android:button" property:

```
<ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/check"   //check.xml
    android:background="@null"/>
```

check.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_image"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_image"
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    </selector>
```

Comment: ToggleButton has parent CompoundButton. And CompoundButton has android:button attribute: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#CompoundButton_button

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The accepted answer results in stretched drawables.

Comment: If images have transparency, `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` can be used

Comment: @Bamerza, no this doesn't apply to all cases either. If you try it with .svg you'll get stretched background.

Comment: What if I don't want to have text used, and only drawables? Still possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this.
Here on click of image button I toggle the imageview.

```
holder.imgitem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!onclick){
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) view.getTag(), true);
            holder.imgoverlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ipad_768x1024_editmode_delete_overlay_com);
            onclick=true;}
            else if(onclick)
            {
                 mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) view.getTag(), false);
                  holder.imgoverlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ipad_768x1024_editmode_selection_com);

            onclick=false;
            }
        }
    });
```