# Create ToggleButton with custom Icon above text, like Quick settings panel

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Just like in this image there is Icon of Wifi , Bluetooth , Brightness etc.
Icons can be toggled using this solution : [Toggle button using two image on different state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499574/toggle-button-using-two-image-on-different-state)

But I don't understand how this is single complete Togglebutton, with Icon above the Text on/off.
so how to create ToggleButton with custom Icon above text like Quick settings panel.

Also,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected, use grey -->
<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
      android:state_checked="true" />
<!-- When not selected, use white-->
<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"
      android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

In above code, android:drawableTop does not work for me.

Comment: You could make a custom view.

Comment: any other way? and what to do in custom view?

Comment: Make a class that extends Button or View and override the important methods such as [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)