# Android Set button color on first click, unset on second click

Tags: android, button, colors

please i need help on this.
I have searched here but the answers i have seen are not working for me, the posts being old, the functions are mostly deprecated.

I am trying to set the color of buttons on a single click in order to highlight them and unset the color on a second click. It's like making some choice from a number of buttons, and if I click on a selected button again maybe after changing my mind on my selection, the color should revert to the default. So that i am only left with the selected buttons highlighted.
The buttons are generated with an adapter in gridview and the onclicklistener applies to all of them.
The code i'm using is as shown:

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
         private Context context;            

         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 

         {            
             final Button btn;  
          if (convertView == null) {    

           btn = new Button(context);  
           btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(40, 40));  
           btn.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);  
           }   
          else {  
           btn = (Button) convertView;  
          }  
          //exus

          btn.setText(Integer.toString(gridNumbers[position]));   

          btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);               
          btn.setId(position);
          btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (v.getSolidColor()!=Color.GREEN)
                {
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);            

                }
                else
                {
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                }

            }
        });

          return btn;  
         }  
        }
}
```

My XML:

```
<GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="8"
        android:columnWidth="20dp"          
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"           
        android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [Toggle Button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View reused in GridView. So, you should define state for your buttons in your base adapters.

Take an ArrayList that will hold your selected index and remove it when grid is not selected.

Ex:

```
ArrayList<Integer> selectedItems;
```

In Construtor

```
selectedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

In OnClickListener

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (selectedItems.contains(new Integer(position))) {
     selectedItems.remove(new Integer(position));
     notifyDataSetChanged();    
} else {
    selectedItems.add(new Integer(position));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

In getView():

```
if (selectedItems.contains(new Integer(position))) {
         btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);    
    } else {
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list of boolean properties instead of doing this.
Set a public boolean list in your class (it should be public and outside of any functions otherwise the onclicklistener will have error)

```
List<boolean> blist=new Arraylist<boolean>(Size);

//Size is maximum number of buttons

int index;
```

Then whenever you create a new button add this:

```
blist.add(index,false);
index++;
```

in the onclicklistener; find the index of the button from its position and save the index in an integer named pos.

```
if(blist.get(pos)==false)
{
 //not clicked yet
 blist.remove(pos);
blist.add(pos,true);
//here write the code u need for this if
}
else
{
blist.remove(pos);
blist.add(pos,false);
//todo: ur code for else
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i've not tried it, i will try it and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

I tried this way and it worked for me,if you want to change on click

```
counter = 1;
        //By Default set color
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (counter == 1)
                {
                   // Default color
                    counter = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    //your color
                    counter = 1;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [toggle button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) insted of normal button. Like

```
<ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/check"   //check.xml
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

and then make an xml file check.xml in drawable folder something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_image"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_image"
        android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

[refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499574/toggle-button-using-two-image-on-different-state).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. but the buttons i'm using were not generated using xml layout, but dynamically with arrayadapter in gridview

Comment: use ToggleButton insted of Button in your code and dynamically set properties to it .. i did not try it myself but it should work as good as a normal Button does.. reffer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29

Comment: Thanks i will try it and get back to you...tried Chirag Jain's suggestion and it works.