# Creating custom switch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-switch

Can anyone help me out in creating a switch like the one shown below?

[image]

The button in the switch can be dragged to the other side as well. It will change position on click just as the button crosses half from its current position. The text in the button also changes. Here is what I am referring to:

[image]

I've researched on switches on Android but none of them gave me this result. I've also looked at the toggle button but that did not do the trick either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle button using two image on different state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499574/toggle-button-using-two-image-on-different-state)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to custom switch button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the answer in this link [How to custom switch button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button)!

Just use the `Selector`to define the `On/Off` states of the `Switch` as follows:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off"  />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on"  />
</selector>
```