# How to create gps toogle icon in android

Tags: android

I am a newbie to Android. My task is to create a gps icon with toggle action.

Fore example, when the icon is clicked, it should have toggle effect.

[image]

When the image is clicked the center should fill with color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11499595

Use a ToggleButton and define a xml resource to change the buttons image depending on it's "activated" state.