# Is it possible to dynamically change the ON color of a Switch widget?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-switch

I am building an app where I want to let the user have the option to change up some colors.

Here's what the app looks like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxeOm.jpg

I want the "Aspect" color to determine the "Notifications" `Switch`'s color.
I know how to set it to a different one at launch but I can't seem to find a way to do it dynamically. I don't even know if it is possible but any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can do this is using a selectors and styles, I hit the same roadblock some time ago. I guess you are using the aspect color for the tint of widgets.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499574/toggle-button-using-two-image-on-different-state) is how you can make a selector.

The problem with selectors is that they consist of two images that switch depending on the toggle state. Also, they don't have the tint propierty avaliable. You have to make a lot of selectors for each color avaliable in the aspect option, and then setting them for each theme. Then you have to switch the theme in runtime, with:

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dark);
```

Maybe there's a new toggle button or custom widget that allows you to do this, but I don't know if it exists.