# How to change two button images when clicking one in Android?

Tags: java, android, image, button, pressed

I am creating an **Android, java-based Minesweeper** knock-off for a college project.

Right now, I can't find how to set two buttons to *pressed state* and make them both revert to *not-pressed* again after releasing the click (more specifically the "emoticon button", when pressing one of the 1, 2, blank or mine buttons). That's what I mean: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XX0q.png).

I tried setting the Smile button to pressed state with: `buttonEmotikon.setPressed(!buttonEmotikon.isActivated());` and `<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/wow"/>` in the xml, but it doesn't change back to primary image after the onClick instruction.

This is the full xml file for smile button:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/wow"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/sad"/>
    </item>
    <item android:state_first="true" android:drawable="@drawable/smile2"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/smile2"/>
</selector>
```

This is an excerpt of the layout with smile button and generic grey button (which is the same as the rest):

```
`<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/block"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton25"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton20"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton24"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            android:src="@drawable/field_bomb" tools:ignore="RtlCompat"/>
    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="49dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/smile2"
            android:id="@+id/buttonEmotikon" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.488" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.019" android:src="@drawable/emotikon" tools:ignore="RtlCompat"/>`
```

My onClick method looks like:

```
`@Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent;
        v.setActivated(!v.isActivated());
        v.setEnabled(false);
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonEmotikon:
```

` and there are cases with different button ids. All clickable objects are ImageButtons.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add full code of drawable resource and layout

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've updated the first post with more code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use selector as background of ToggleButton and place your images in proper states like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499574/toggle-button-using-two-image-on-different-state)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0):

To change the image to the boolean value of isActivated, add the following code:

```
<item android:state_activated="false">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/smile2"/>
</item>
```